# event.localX of a MovieClip regardless of any other DisplayObject over/under/inside

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, gesture

Here is an example:

```
var table:Table = new Table();
stage.addChild(table);
//table covers the whole stage
for (var i:int = 0; i<= 10; i++){
  var book:Book = new Book();
  book.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
  book.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
  if (Math.random() < .5){
    stage.addChild(book)
  }
  else {
    table.addChild(book)
  }

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);

function clicked(event:MouseEvent){
trace(event.localX, event.localY);
}
```

what i need here is the localX or localY OF THE TABLE, not anything else.

so the general question is "how to return event.localX of a certain MovieClip regardless of any other DisplayObject over/under/inside it, without setting the mouseChildren to false (as I need them to be enabled)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DisplayObject`'s globalToLocal method to convert a `Point` from being relative to the stage to being relative to the table object.

```
function clicked(event:MouseEvent){
    var globalPt:Point = new Point(event.stageX, event.stageY); 
    var tablePt:Point = table.globalToLocal(globalPt);
    trace(tablePt.x, tablePt.y);
}
```